# Split screen in Google Hangout

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm trying to create a Google Hangout during a speech where I have two cameras, one pointing at the speaker, and the other pointing at the audience. I would like it so that I could broadcast both videos streams together on one screen, so that other people who join can view both of them without having to switch back and forth between the two cameras.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it sounds a little awkward I can think of the following:

1. Both recorders join the Hangout (Speaker + Audience).
2. Two viewers join from one computer (need two accounts), one selects the Speaker, one the Audience.
3. On the viewer-computer arrange the two windows any way you want to divide it.
4. Share that computer's screen.

I don't know any way to do it out of the box in Hangouts, but this is a possibility that could work—or even multiple different views.

Of course the delay increases. So ensure you are testing it and ensure sound is synchronous.